# vertices a great distance, only hold down ctrl they move slower

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, edit-mode

Vertices only move when I hold down the ctrl key, otherwise they move a great distance.

Comment: you must have enabled the Snapping option (magnet icon on top of the 3D view)

Comment: Thank you, dude!!!!!!